# How to parse empty value of parameter in HTTP request in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi, urllib, python-3.2

I parse the following request `param1=value1&param2=&param3=value3` using `urllib.parse.parse_qs` (python 3 wsgi application) but this function returns a dict with only `param1` and `param3` keys. What function can I use to get also the empty `param2`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's right there in the documentation for [`parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

> The optional argument *keep_blank_values* is a flag indicating whether blank values in percent-encoded queries should be treated as blank strings. A true value indicates that blanks should be retained as blank strings. The default false value indicates that blank values are to be ignored and treated as if they were not included.

In other words, instead of

```
>>> parse_qs(querystring)
{'param1': ['value1'], 'param3': ['value3']}
```

... you need:

```
>>> parse_qs(querystring, keep_blank_values=True)
{'param2': [''], 'param1': ['value1'], 'param3': ['value3']}
```

Comment: You are right. I have seen this parameter but I have though that it is about spaces which is not represented in percent-encoded form.